# Merge array based on their key by value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I've this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 99
            [fruit] => Apple
            [color] => Green
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 99
            [fruit] => Apple
            [color] => Red
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 555
            [fruit] => Banada
            [color] => Yellow
        )
)
```

I need to create a new array from this one by merging item by `id`.

So the final output is the following:

```
Array
(
    [99] => Array
        (
            [id] => 99
            [fruit] => Apple
            [color] => Green
        ),
        (
            [id] => 99
            [fruit] => Apple
            [color] => Red
        )
    [555] => Array
        (
            [id] => 555
            [fruit] => Banada
            [color] => Yellow
        )
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try looping through your data, and make a new array based on the id. `$new_array[$item['id']][] = $item`. You can use foreach to loop through your data, with `foreach ($data as $item)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a new array to hold the results and iterate over the input, adding every element to the new array. Notice how PHP creates the subarrays automatically.

```
$output = array();
foreach($input as $fruit){
    $output[$fruit['id']][] = $fruit;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZFBC4JAEIXPza9YRHAXOlTgQczCLt27hUgs7YqCucumRUS/fVN3CSuKTr3T8N4bvoGRudR6vpS5BLeoZFOjCMVK0QtgQK0mKFpYA1nhx9TJKZjTdYJg/OxnqinqPnJiKUvuvOR7UQpl8rXivBrkxIzTf7A3nL2TZ7@Sfd//jF7RijL6hb3lZSnOQzyQEMAVTW0@QbsTcOtlQnG6z7H9ET0itweRK4xsPTFO4hXMS9MkbdeNE8IN4ETVjjUHiW2bhFrfAQ)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function merge_array_by_key($arrays)
{
    $new_array = [];
    foreach($arrays as $array)
    {
        $new_array[$array["id"]] = $array;
    }
    return $new_array;
}
```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to loop each item of the array.
If you use array_column and array_intersect(_key) then you only need to loop the unique IDs in the array.
I added array_values to just to make sure you get 0 indexed arrays, but if that is not important, then you can remove it.

```
$ids = array_column($arr, "id");

Foreach(array_unique($ids) as $id){
    $new[$id] = array_values(array_intersect_key($arr, array_intersect($ids, [$id])));
}
Var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/YJWuV

---

Or you can get a slightly more condensed output with adding another array_column on the "color".

```
$ids = array_column($arr, "id");

Foreach(array_unique($ids) as $id){
    $temp = array_values(array_intersect_key($arr, array_intersect($ids, [$id])));
    $new[$id] = ['fruit' => $temp[0]['fruit'], 'color' => array_column($temp, "color")];
}
Var_dump($new);
```

This outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [99]=>
  array(2) {
    ["fruit"]=>
    string(5) "Apple"
    ["color"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "Green"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "Red"
    }
  }
  [555]=>
  array(2) {
    ["fruit"]=>
    string(6) "Banana"
    ["color"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "Yellow"
    }
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/FLNcW